# Flowable inside of ViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, rx-java, rx-java2

I have been started programming in android again and since it has been changed a lot in the last 4 years I got a little bit confused. I am trying to load my data from the server asynchronously with RxJava and Flowable inside of my ViewHolder. I am using a third-party library to handle my views in adaptor [MultiViewAdaptor](https://github.com/DevAhamed/MultiViewAdapter). Here is my code in my **Binder**

```
class FooBinder : ItemBinder<Foo, FooBinder.ViewHolder>() {

        @Inject
        protected lateinit var requestFavoriteUseCase: SendFooFavoriteUseCase

        @Inject
        protected lateinit var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable

        @Inject
        protected lateinit var retrieveFooFavoriteCountUseCase: RetrieveFooFavoriteCountUseCase

        override fun create(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) =
            ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_foo_content, parent, false))

        override fun bind(holder: ViewHolder, item: Foo) {
            holder.itemView.foo_content_creator.text = with(item.creator) { "$firstName $lastName" }

            GlideApp.with(holder.itemView)
                .load(item.creator.avatar)
                .dontAnimate()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_person)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_action_person)
                .into(holder.itemView.foo_content_profile)

            retrieveFooFavoriteCountUseCase
                    .execute(item.id)
                    .applyComputationScheduler()
                    .subscribe { count ->
                        holder.itemView.foo_content_like_count.text = "$count"
                    }
                    .addTo(compositeDisposable)
        }

        inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : ViewHolder<Foo>(view) {

            private var favorite = false

            init {

                view
                    .foo_content_button_layout
                    .clicks()
                    .flatMap {
                        favorite = !favorite
                        requestFavoriteUseCase.execute(FavoriteVM(item.id, favorite)).toObservable()
                    }
                    .subscribe {
                        view.foo_content_like_count.text = it.toString()

                        var res = R.drawable.ic_action_like_default
                        if (favorite) {
                            res = R.drawable.ic_action_like_enabled
                        }
                        view.foo_content_like_icon.setImageResource(res)
                    }
                    .addTo(compositeDisposable)
            }

        }

    }
```

As you see I have to call server in **bind** method which is not ideal and it is being called every time user scrolls also I cannot unsubscibe them till the Activity is destored and **compositeDisposable** is called which means I am going to have multi disposable for one view :(

My question is, how can I use observable inside of ViewHolder and stop feeding it when it is not shown in screen?

Answer (score 3):

The best thing you can do is:

1. Rely on `onViewAttachedToWindow` and `onViewDetachedToWindow` to control your subscription lifecycle (subscribe/dispose).
2. Create/retrieve your observables on `onBindViewHolder`
3. Nullify your adapter on recycler in parent view (fragment/activity) to force adapter to call `onViewDetachedToWindow` for all of the windows to make sure you're not leaking anything (example for fragment, in `onDestoryView` call `list.adapter = null`)
4. Add `delaySubscription`(400ms for example) to your observables to reduce lagging while scrolling fast (you don't want to subscribe to anything while list is sliding on animation)
5. Make sure your observables' first emission is synchronous, so the cached data can be delivered before layout after screen rotation. This way you will avoid animation glitches during rotation and Android will be able to restore the View state properly.

Point 5 might be a little bit confusing so there is some resources explaining this more broadly:

- [Enabling Android Teams: Where the Reactive Rubber Meets the Road by Ray Ryan](http://nabling%20Android%20Teams:%20Where%20the%20Reactive%20Rubber%20Meets%20the%20Road%20by%20Ray%20Ryan)
- [RxAndroid new async api](https://medium.com/@ZacSweers/rxandroids-new-async-api-4ab5b3ad3e93)
- [Article about restoring view state properly](https://medium.com/@dimezis/android-scroll-position-restoring-done-right-cff1e2104ac7)
- [RxAndroid Github issue providing some more insights](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/pull/228)

So basically synchronous emission means that item is going to be emitted while subscribing to observable, before subscribe method returns. For example this behaviour might be achieved with some kind of caching (like replay(1), startWith() etc) in a chain that is not modifying subscription emission threads after the cache.

Example:

```
Observable.create(2)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .startWith(0)
    .subscribe(println(it))

println("after subscribe")
```

Let say we subscribe on a main thread. In that case we are going to print:

```
    0
    after subscribe
    2
```

So as you can see, even though both items are going to be emitted on a main thread, one of those is going to arrive immediately while subscribing, whereas second one is going to be posted on a looper.

Comment: Thank you @Than, the way you describe is very helpful and give me the idea but could you please explain more or even show me an example if you have about items 3 and 5?

Comment: @navid_gh as for the point 5 it's tricky one, I've provided you some articles about this thingy as it requires some more knowledge about threading in Rx and Android. However you can try to implement it without it, proposed solution by me is for streams that emits multiple values per each list item and the rotation glitch is not that much visible. So you might not need everything in your project

Answer (score 0):

`bind` methods (originally, `onBindViewHolder`) called every time when view try to show to the user. (Indeed, this methods called again when the user had scroll to the bottom and to up)

So, **called network process on onBindViewHolder is a bad idea** in terms of lifecycle issues or performance.

I suggested this way to achieve this.

1. getting all data associated `item.id` before initializing adapter.
2. Matching data with Foo and retrieved data
3. Initialize adapter with the result of Step 2.
4. In `onBindViewHolder`, `holder.itemView.foo_content_like_count.text = item.count` instead subscribe retrieveFooFavoriteCountUseCase.

Example code, it's may not working well. I just give how it works.)

```
  val items = ...
  retrieveFooFavoriteCountUseCase
      .execute(items.map { it.id }) // 1)
      .applyComputationScheduler()
      .subscribe { counts -> 
          for ((index, count) in counts.indexed()) { // 2)
              items[index] = items[index].apply { this.count = count } // 3)
          }

          // TODO: initialize adapter with items
      }.addTo(compositeDisposable)
```

1) you should implement execute methods with List? I don't know the specific type of Foo.

2) counts contains List of count you need. In this example code, I used for-each to matching data. but you can use own matching code.

3) Same as above, you can use own matching code.

As a result, subscribe will be called only once during the entire process.

Comment: I appreciate the time you spent to reply. So if I understood correctly, I need to manipulate the item (Foo) that is being sent to the bind method instead of having the network call inside of the Binder or ViewHolder? right? if so, it is not going to work for me as I want to have the items flowable as well, my data is changing regularly by server and as it is streaming it should reflect the changes, getting all data before initializing adapter does not work, also I am not sending list to adapter I am sending Foo (my class) one by one and add it to adapter items

Comment: If you can observe 'timing of changing data from server', it can be resolved in this way.

1. Initialize adapter.
2. observe 'timing of changing data' in Activity. when data has come, getting change data from the server.
3. update item and notify to the adapter by ```notifyItemChanged(position)```. it can reflect changes from the server.

I think this method is better than managing the Disposable object in RecyclerView's adapter.